# OCaml Bytes to Bigarray

Tags: ocaml, zeromq, bytestream

I have a C program that has in memory an array of `double` or an array of `int`. The C program sends the corresponding binary data using ZeroMQ to an OCaml program. The OCaml program receives some `bytes`, and now I want to transform these `bytes` into an `Array of int` or an `Array of float`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ocplib-endian](https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocplib-endian/blob/master/src/endianString.cppo.mli) to read the raw values from the string.

For example, a function to read `double` values from a `string` buffer:

```
let read_double buf offset =
  (* Multiply by 8 for 8-byte doubles *)
  EndianString.LE.get_double buf (offset * 8)
```

If you know/check/assume that the string is nothing but `double`s then you can use the `read_double` function like this to build an array:

```
let read_array buf =
  (* Again, 8 for 8-byte doubles *)
  let length = String.length buf / 8 in
  Array.init length (fun i -> read_double buf i)
```

This is all untested, so beware of typos!  There are likely ways to make it more efficient as well, although this implementation shouldn't be too bad for normal use.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! This answer is very helpful.